# How do I display Python output on a HTML page

Tags: python

When I run the Python script it runs perfectly fine and displays the output on the shell however I want to display the output in html, how do I do it?

I already use Django but I feel like it is very tedious to display it on the html page. Do any of you know how to retrieve the output from shell to html page without being it to complicated?

I also tried REMI, and many more but I can't seem to find the perfect way to display it

Comment: Try Flask (https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/).

Comment: You can't simply take text and display as html. You need to wrap your text in some html tags and then display it. There are numerous html tags available, so you need to be more specific as to what kind of html output you want. You may also want to look into a markdown-to-html converter for python.

Comment: what will markdown to html do?

Comment: You can put text in `<pre></pre>` in HTML and it will keep format - it will move text to new line on `\n`. In normal HTML you have to replace `\n` with `<br/>`

Comment: if you want to generate HTML without creatin WWW server then you can get your text and add strings with HTML - ie. `"<pre>" + text + "</pre>"` - and you can save in file.